# "50 shades of Gray" in UIImage... (I thought I'd make this more attractive)

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiimage

I'm looking for an easy way to assign to a shape (image.png) that I've got a shade of gray.

i.e depending on a value that I've got ranging from 0 to 1 I would like my shape (image.png) to appear black (value 0) to white (value 1000).

The original color of my shape (image.png) is white.

```
UIImage *shape = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't an acceptable answer in the stackoverflow community so i'll write it in the comments. The technique is called masking. I will take a shot at writing you some code a bit later, but for now, I'll leave you this link. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html

Comment: Thanks. I have tried masking but I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this. What I am doing now is (works but it's not very accurate) is that I have two identical images (one black and one white on top of each other) and play with the alpha so I can achieve some gray shades... But as I said is not very accurate. –  George Asda 16 mins ago   delete

Comment: For example say I've got a UISlider with values 0 to 1000 and an UIImage (image.png). When user slides the slider image "color" changes from white to black (passing through gray values).

Comment: What is in the image? Is it solid color or something with transparency? It has only white with levels of alpha?

Comment: It's an irregular shape, with transparency, solid white color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate**

```
imageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"shapeWithTransparancy"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:sliderVal alpha:1.];
```

Comment: thats it! that's exactly what I wanted! thanks mate!

Comment: Keep in mind, that if the user enables _Darken Colors_ in their Accessibility Settings, you will have wrong colors.

Comment: Also, for any other color than gray, this solution fails when `tintAdjustmentMode` becomes `UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not looking for colors other than gray. I will also make put a warning about "Darken Colors". Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use masking of `CALayer`, where you just use another `CALayer` to crop it.

1. Create `UIView` with solid color – the desired shade of gray.
2. Create `CALayer` with the image and assign it as a mask.
3. You can change the background color at any time.

Code:

```
UIView *imageView = [[UIView alloc] init]; // We call it "image" view ;)
imageView.frame = placeItWhereverYouWant;

CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (__bridge id)[yourImageHere CGImage];
mask.frame = imageView.layer.bounds; // Frame of the mask is sometimes tricky.
imageView.layer.mask = mask;

CGFloat shadeOfGray = 0.7;
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:shadeOfGray alpha:1];
```

Comment: This is really _not_ complicated. This is the proper way to do masking and using `tintColor` (in the other answer) is just a trick to achieve similar effect.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't looking for masking though. I was looking for minimal effort to do what is described above as the accepted answer.